# Internal reference for SOQL sub-query

Tags: soql, query

As below:

```
SELECT *Id*,Owner.Name,CreatedDate,
(SELECT AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId = {!ParentQuery.Id}) 
FROM Account WHERE ispersonaccount = false ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST
```

Another way I've tried this is:

```
SELECT Id,Owner.Name,CreatedDate FROM Account 
WHERE ispersonaccount = false AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId from Opportunity) 
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST
```

Basically, as above where I would like the values returned on each subquery to be the opps related to the ID of each row of the main query.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the join works. You don't need to add any extra query syntax. The sub-select will only give you the child records related to that row. It acts like an additional field on each record, with your child relationship name as the field, and which stores a collection.

```
for (Account record : [SELECT Name, (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunities) FROM Account])
{
    for (Opportunity child : record.Opportunities)
    {
        system.assertEquals(record.Id, child.AccountId);
    }
}
```

See also [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join):

> ## [Left Outer Join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join)
>
> **Problem:** Find all positions with their related list of applications.
>
> Again, we would like to list the positions regardless of whether there is a related application or not.
>
> **SOQL Query:**
>
> ```
> SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Job_Applications__r) FROM Position__c
> ```
>
> **Results:**
>
> [image: LeftOuterJoin.jpg]
>
> **Discussion:**
>
> Note that we have utilized a NESTED select to obtain the records of related children from the parent. This kind of expression is very powerful in obtaining related records traversing from the 1 side in a 1-m relationship. In complex data modeling, especially with containment relationships, it is a useful pattern to obtain related information on a parent and all its children via traversing path expressions with relationship fields. In this example, we are utilizing a path expression from Position__c using the relationship, Job_Applications__r to obtain the list of applicants to create this join. This pattern will also be very useful in obtaining data from feeds in Chatter which will be discussed elsewhere. Please note that the result set is a list of positions where each position contains a list of application, reflecting the nature of the hierarchical representation of the data that is selected by this query.And is very useful Information for the beginners.